# No way to infer the exact line number of this "print_block" definition execution without metaprogramming in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am working with Elixir...I found that when defining the below code without macros, I have to put inspect `__ENV__` and subtract 2 from the printed line number to get the line number that `print_block` is getting run on.

```
h1 do
  h2 do
    print_block "prints message" do
      IO.puts "hello world!"
      IO.inspect(__ENV__)
    end
  end
end
```

The function definition of print_block then looks something like:

```
def print_block(_msg, do: code_block), do: code_block
```

Similar code defines h1 and h2 blocks.

Now if I instead define `h1`, `h2`, and `print_block` as macros, I'm able to get the exact line number of `print_block` in the existing file by walking the AST produced when I inspect `code_block`.

```
defmacro print_block(_msg, do: code_block) do
  IO.inspect(code_block)
  code_block
end
```

Because Elixir metaprogramming lets you examine the AST, the only way to match on exact the line number of print_block without resorting to "subtracting some number" then is to define it via macros. You can't do it with traditional run-time modules/functions, is that correct? Pretty sure that's the case, just looking to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because Elixir metaprogramming lets you examine the AST [...]

This is not exactly the case. What macro does, it literally *injects* the AST in the place of the call *before compilation happens*. The compiled code has no trail of any macro, they are all gone, substituted by AST they returned during the compilation stage.

That means, your macro does not work as you expect. `IO.inspect` is executed *during the compilation stage*. The BEAM won’t print out anything, nor there would be any `__ENV__.line` or like accessible.

OTOH, [`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2) has a specifically dedicated `location: :keep` option to preserve the file and line number. It won’t happen automatically out of the box.

Also, there is [`@compile`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html#module-compile) module attribute one might put into modules to specify which functions should be inlined; basically inlining does nearly the same as calling macro.

---

I was unable to understand what is the exact goal you are after, but the assumption that macro would magically help to notch the exact line number is plain wrong.

---

Here is a demonstration of all the possibilities to get a line from `__ENV__`:

```
bat /tmp/foo.ex
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /tmp/foo.ex
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ defmodule Foo do
   2   │   @compile {:inline, print_block_inline: 2}
   3   │ 
   4   │   def print_block_inline(_msg, do: code_block), do: code_block
   5   │   def print_block_normal(_msg, do: code_block), do: code_block
   6   │   defmacro print_block_macro(_msg, do: code_block), do: code_block
   7   │ 
   8   │   def test do
   9   │     print_block_normal "prints message" do
  10   │       IO.puts("hello world!")
  11   │       IO.inspect(__ENV__.line, label: "11")
  12   │     end
  13   │ 
  14   │     print_block_inline "prints message" do
  15   │       IO.puts("hello world!")
  16   │       IO.inspect(__ENV__.line, label: "16")
  17   │     end
  18   │ 
  19   │     print_block_macro "prints message" do
  20   │       IO.puts("hello world!")
  21   │       IO.inspect(__ENV__.line, label: "21")
  22   │     end
  23   │   end
  24   │ end
  25   │ 
  26   │ Foo.test()
```

Everything is successfully printed.

```
elixir /tmp/foo.ex

hello world!
11: 11
hello world!
16: 16
hello world!
21: 21
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexsei, I was just trying to understand why I got something like ```[line: 13], ["hello world"]},...``` (abbreviated for clarity) when I did an IO.inspect(code_block) on a macro defined function like print_block.  line 13 is the exact number in the file that IO.puts("hello world") is on. I don't think you can do that with a non-macro function?